# EKS cluster autoscaler: Failed to regenerate ASG cache: cannot autodiscover ASGs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, autoscaling

I am trying to deploy cluster autoscaling (CA) in EKs cluster. Attached policy mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/autoscaling.html) to my worker node role. Created deployment, service account and other resources as mentioned on [github page](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/examples/cluster-autoscaler-autodiscover.yaml).
However, after deploying cluster-autoscalar pod is going in crashloopback. It is throwing below error-

> aws_manager.go:262] Failed to regenerate ASG cache: cannot autodiscover ASGs: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
> For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
> F1202 18:02:16.712812       1
> aws_cloud_provider.go:382] Failed to create AWS Manager: cannot autodiscover ASGs: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
> For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors

Can someone please suggest what I am missing here ?

**Few of the details are as-**
EKS version:-  1.16.
autoscalar version:- v1.16.6.
AWS region:-  ap-south-1.

**Note:-** I want to create without using [IAM OIDC.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/autoscaling.html)

Comment: Are you blocking IDMS on your nodes? If you are, IAM OIDC or kube2iam is required.

Comment: how can I check IDMS ?

Comment: You could try to query instance metadata from a pod and see if its blocked. Otherwise you can check if any of these configurations for blocking have been applied to the cluster: https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/security/docs/iam/#restrict-access-to-the-instance-profile-assigned-to-the-worker-node